# Restrict certain tags from non-admins in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, privileges, user-roles

I run a multiple author website. I want to restrict a few tags from being selected by my authors.

The only options that I found so far was techniques to replace the free tag text field with a list (similar to the category list). This is not a solution for me as I will need my authors to be able to create new tags.

Surely there must be a way to restrict specific tags from non-admins? Do you know how? Any brainstorming or proper solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ideal solution would be to conditionally filter the taxonomy query used in `post_tags_meta_box` as it ajaxes its suggestions, and maybe even providing some error-handling if someone tried to manually type the tag you don't want them to use, but I'm not aware of a filter that could aid in pulling that off.

Expanding on Giordano's suggestion and referencing [this other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/problem-with-removing-post-tags-programmatically), you could use something like this in functions.php

```
add_action('save_post', 'remove_tags_function', 10, 1); //whenever a post is saved, run the below function

function remove_tags_function( $post_id ){
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){ // if the logged in user cannot manage options (only admin can)
        $post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag', array( 'fields'=>'names' ) ); //grab all assigned post tags
        $pos = array_search( 'tag-to-be-deleted', $post_tags ); //check for the prohibited tag
        if( false !== $pos ) { //if found
            unset( $post_tags[$pos] ); //unset the tag
            wp_set_post_terms ($post_id, $post_tags, 'post_tag'); //override the posts tags with all prior tags, excluding the tag we just unset
        }
    }//end if. If the current user CAN manage options, the above lines will be skipped, and the tag will remain
}
```

Non-admin users will still be able to type in and add `tag-to-be-deleted`, but it will not stick to the post. Once saved, the tag will be stripped. If the user is really dedicated, they could spell it differently, or, as you saw, change the capitalization, but whatever they do it wont technically be the same tag, and you will be able to keep it pure for whatever theme purpose you need. I can't imagine a situation in which a user without admin capabilities could add the forbidden tag, but I know better than to never say never.

If you want to allow certain non-admin users to assign the forbidden tag to a post, you'll have to revise the parameter passed into line 4 `if(!current_user_can('...'){`. For information on other capabilities you can pass to this conditional statement, check the [Wordpress documentation of Roles & Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities). It's much easier to check for a capability than a role, so pick a logical capability that is restricted to the levels of user that you wish to be exempt from the tag deletion.

Comment: I added this code in my function.php and replaced the tag-to-be-deleted with the restricted tag that I wanted, but it did not work. While logged in on a user with author level, it still appeared in the list. Maybe there is a typo in your code? Any other solutions?

Comment: You should do a new post cycle while logged in as a non-admin user. Try adding the tag and saving the post and then refreshing to see if the tag sticks.

Comment: I did as you proposed without success. I created a new post with an author leveled user, added the tag, saved the post. Tag is still there. Double checked by logging out and logging in as Admin and it is there for sure. Did this work for you? Any further ideas? Thank you for the assistance regardless.

Comment: Sorry, the `is_admin` conditional I had used actually checks to see if the Dashboard is being displayed, which, when adding tags, will typically return true. I've changed it to `current_user_can('manage_options')`, which should work!

Comment: It still did not work brother. I added your updated code and made a fresh test following the same steps that I listed before, the tag remains. Is there any chance that you have another issue in your code?

Comment: Also to note, the only thing that I changed in your code was the **tag-to-be-deleted**.

Comment: What was `if (!is_admin()){` should instead be `if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){`. It's working for me! Double check the most recent edit to my answer and try again. If that doesn't work, let me know what version of Wordpress you're using.

Comment: I am running version 3.4.1 of Wordpress. And I used the updated code. I will redo this again to double check. Can you please confirm the functions of this code? If I understand it correctly, the user can select the tag, but once the post is saved, the tag is deselected?

Comment: Hold on, I see now what the issue was. I was using the slug for the tag. I used the name for it this time (just a capital change) and it worked! Before I jump out of joy and give you a medal for solving this issue, can you please explain how this script works **and** if the user can bypass it in any way?

Comment: And how do I change the user level of who that can use the tag, is this done by changing the number 10 in the first line? If you could please update your answer with this and my above request, I will accept this as the correct answer. Also, please comment your paypal email and I will send through a few $ for your effort. You have no idea how much this particular issue has been destroying my work process this week.

Comment: Gary, I've added comments to each line of the function that should help you understand the process, and I've included information about changing the restriction to affect different levels of users. As for payment, I am more than happy to help, and I'm glad to contribute to the SO community. Maybe someday you will do the same.

Comment: Oh I see. It is based on capabilities. In this case, it allows users that can **manage_options** which is set to admins by default. Excellent update of your question and guidelines, I have obviously accepted this answer as correct. I am indeed an avid user of a different stackexchange platform and I do contribute there extensively. However, my coding knowledge is limited meaning that I am mostly asking rather than answering here on SO. However, I should note that from my experience here so far, your returning support has probably been the best that I have received here. Thanks again brother!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a simple plugin that deletes the specified tags from the post when saved if the author is not you.
You can call your function when the post is saved with `add_action('save_post', 'remove_tags_function',10,2);`

Then you would create a function like

```
function remove_tags_function($postID, $post){
if($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision($postID))
    {
    $postID = $parent_id;
    $post = get_post($postID);
    }
if($post->post_author != 'YOUR AUTHOR NUMBER'){
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id );
$i = 0;
foreach($tags as $tag){
 if(in_array("TAG NAME", $tag)) unset $tags[$i];
 $i++;
}

}}
```

I have not tested it, but logically it would work.

EDIT:

That's not gonna work!

Try to put the following in a .php file in your plugin folder. Not tested for now, but it looks fine.

```
<?php
add_action('save_post', 'remove_tags_function',10,2);
        function remove_tags_function($postID, $post){
        if($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision($postID))
            {
            $postID = $parent_id;
            $post = get_post($postID);
            }
        $user_info = $user_info = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        if($user_info->user_level != 10){ // 10 = admin
        untag_post($postID, array('TAGS', ... ));

        }}
        function untag_post($post_ids, $tags) {
        global $wpdb;
        if(! is_array($post_ids) ) {
            $post_ids = array($post_ids);
        }
        if(! is_array($tags) ) {
            $tags = array($tags);
        }

        foreach($post_ids as $post_id) {
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'post_tag');
            $newterms = array();
            foreach($terms as $term) {
                if ( !in_array($term->name,$tags) ) { //$term will be a wordpress Term object.
                    $newterms[] = $term;
                }
            }
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $newterms, 'post_tag', FALSE);
        }
    } // I got this from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/remove-tags-from-posts-in-php/49256#49256
?>
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. Is there any possibility that you can kindly elaborate on your answer? Maybe with a working code example that I can test run to see if it functions?

Comment: Is there any possibility to add this in the function.php file and make it work this way?

Comment: You would need to create a .php file and drop it in the plugin folder. Now that I think about it, you can't just unset the tag, you would need to remove it with something like a specific function. I'll look into it later tonight.

Comment: Thank you very much. Obviously I am in desperate need of a solution to this issue. If you get a chance to solve this later tonight, please update this answer. I would not mind passing through a few $ through paypal for your efforts.

Comment: Thank you for the update, however, I tested it without result - most likely because I did not perform the test properly. I copied your code to my plugin folder, choose a specific tag in **untag_post($postID, array('TAGS', ... ));** and then tested it with a none-admin account. It tagged. **However**, I am very uncertain if the plugin is even active. I could not find it listed in my plugin list in wp-admin and from my experience with plugins, you will need to activate them, right? Is there any chance that you can give the code a test yourself and post results?

Comment: I'll be able to do that tomorrow from the office. However, you could try to put that into functions.php and see what happens. I'm not entirely sure about the hook we are using. Also, if you want to be able to add the tags yourself to posts whose author is someone else, you should wrap everything in is_admin() and remove the condition where it checks whether the author is an admin. However, if that was the case, then if you were to put the tag on a post, if it got edited by its author (not admin), the tag would get removed.

Comment: This issue has been solved by crowjonah, however, thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

based on crowjonah's wonderful answer, here is a function to remove multiple tags:

```
<?php           
/** block non-admins from using specific post tags **/
function remove_tags_function( $post_id ){
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){ // if the logged in user cannot manage options (only admin can)
        $post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag', array( 'fields'=>'names' ) ); //grab all assigned post tags
        $pos = array_intersect( array('TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG3', 'ETC...'), $post_tags ); //check for the prohibited tag
        if( !empty($pos) ) { //if found
            $post_tags = array_diff($post_tags, $pos);
            wp_set_post_terms ($post_id, $post_tags, 'post_tag'); //override the posts tags with all prior tags, excluding the tag we just unset
        }
    }//end if. If the current user CAN manage options, the above lines will be skipped, and the tag will remain
}
add_action('save_post', 'remove_tags_function', 10, 1); //whenever a post is saved, run the below function      
?>
```

Itamar